# Critical points and strict local minimum on a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

I reformulated the question and reposted it.

### Let $f: (a, b) \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that for some $c\in (a, b)$, $f(c)$ is a strict local minimum, i.e., exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(c)<f(x)$ for all $x\in (c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$. Suppose also that there is a point $d \in (a, b)$ such that $f(d) \le f(c)$. Show that there is at least one critical point between $c$ and $d$.

It's like adjustmente for the theorem of the intermediate value, for derivatives.
Since $f$ is differenciable, it is continuous.
Is there a contradiction in to say that $f(c)$ is a strict local minimum, i.e., exists $ε>0$ such that $f(c)<f(x)$ for all $x∈(c−ε,c+ε)$, on the way that $f(d) ≤ f(c)$?
How the mean value theorem could help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume WLOG that $d>c+\epsilon.$ Since $f$ is continuous and $f(d)\le f(c)$ there exists $x_0\in (c,d]$ such that $f(c)=f(x_0).$ (See $\bullet$.) Now, it follows from Rolle's theorem that there exists $x_1\in (c,x_0)$ such that $f'(x_1)=0.$

- Consider $f:[c+\epsilon,d]\to \mathbb{R}.$ If $f(d)=f(c)$ we are done. So, assume $f(d)<f(c).$ That is, we have $f(d)<f(c)<f(c+\epsilon).$ It follows from the Intermediate value theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) the existence of $x_0$ such that $f(c)=f(x_0).$